Imported styles from scss module are undefined
I am using CSS Module and SCSS as my styling in my app, but when I import my styles as:
import styles from './landing.module.scss'

The imported styles is undefined.
I am using:
"css-loader": "^7.1.2",
"style-loader": "^4.0.0"
"sass-loader": "^16.0.0",

Here is my webpack config:
// scss loader
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: {
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
        }
      }
    },
    'sass-loader'
  ]
})

// css loader
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
})


The v7.0.0 of css-loader changed the option modules.namedExport to be true by default, requiring imports to now be written from:
import styles from "./landing.module.scss";

To:
import * as styles from "./landing.module.scss";


i don't use css file, i want use module.scss file and trying to import from it and import styles as an object

here is my sandbox:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ucqnqy

@Faraz I just took the example of the release, it works the same for .modules.scss files. The code works on your sandbox, check the console. You also need to update the TS config, as explained on the release of v7.0.0 linked on my answer.

i dont use typescript. and in my sandbox styles did not apply
@Arkellys

@Faraz The StackBitz you shared is in TS, so I assumed you use TS. Your initial question is about styles.container being undefined, my answer solves this problem. Now the styles not applying is the matter of another question, probably just something wrong with your config.

It doesn't, though. Property 'container' does not exist on type 'typeof import("*.module.scss")'. that's the error you get from the sandbox above.
